# What is causing this JavaScript associative array to go out of whack?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I have an associative array that I've verified (via `console.log`) is originally

```
this.RegionsChecked = {"US":true,"APAC":true,"Canada":true,"France":true,"Germany":true,"India":true,"Japan":true,"LATAM":true,"MEA":true,"UK":true,"WE":true};
```

and I have an event handler that attempts to toggle the value of a corresponding item when it is checked/unchecked in the HTML:

```
Calculator.prototype.UpdateGraphs = function ( $elem ) 
{
    // $elem : input[type="checkbox"] element that was clicked, as a jQuery object

    var $parent = $elem.parent(); // Parent of input that was clicked. 
                                  // Will either be a th.region or a td#guiderow-[metric_name]

    if ( $parent.hasClass('region') ) 
    {
        var region_name = $parent.text();
        this.RegionsChecked[region_name] = !this.RegionsChecked[region_name]; // toggle region name
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.RegionsChecked)); // TEST
    }
    // ...
```

What is strange is that when I change the check value of  `Canada`, for example, the array sometimes turns to

```
this.RegionsChecked = {"US":true,"APAC":true,"Canada":true,"France":true,"Germany":true,"India":true,"Japan":true,"LATAM":true,"MEA":true,"UK":true,"WE":true,"\n\t\t\t\t\tCanada":true};
```

(look at the last key, what previously was `"Unknown"`)

instead of the expected

```
this.RegionsChecked = {"US":true,"APAC":true,"Canada":false,"France":true,"Germany":true,"India":true,"Japan":true,"LATAM":true,"MEA":true,"UK":true,"WE":true};
```

which is does **some of the time, I think** (but still have to verify). I'm still trying to figure out how consistently it is happening, but you have any ideas on why?

*EDIT:* Weird ... It just did it correctly. I can't find any discernable pattern in when it works and doesn't .. I am using Microsoft Sharepoint Designer, which can do strange things ...

Comment: If your HTML contains indentation, you’re obviously going to have tabulators in the `.text()` part of your elements.

Comment: @Xufox My HTML shouldn't have any indentations. Can indentations occure on window resize?

Comment: I have no idea. You haven’t even shared your HTML or how it is generated or potentially modified. If you’re seeing a bunch of `\t`s, you shouldn’t rely on what the HTML _should_ be, but on what the HTML _actually is_.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's not a very good idea to depend on the actual *text* of a DOM node as a key for information, especially if that DOM is dynamically generated by a large unwieldy CMS-like like SharePoint that performs various transforms on your text before it ends up in the DOM (using the Designer adds another fun step to that chain). That is what constructs like [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) are for.

That said, if you have to do it, you are probably better off trimming your text before using it. I.e.,

```
var region_name = $.trim($parent.text());
```